# Form Submitting with Jquery in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I wanna submitting form with jquery append. But it doesn't work. I am adding fields but when i click the submit, only original fields sent. Duplicate fields not sending. How can i fix this. And also when i delete the fields, it only delete one field instead of three fields.

first image is original fields.
[image]

Seconda image is clone the fields with jquery
[image]

Third is datas which are sent with form
[image]

Here is my codes...

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mesaj=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Contact
#from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        full_name=request.POST['full_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        mesaj=request.POST['mesaj']
        contact=Contact.objects.create(full_name=full_name,email=email,mesaj=mesaj)
       # messages.success(request,'Data has been submitted')
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

contact.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<form method="post" action="">   
   
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="full_name" class="field-long" />
<input type="text" name="email" class="field-long" />
<input type="text" name="mesaj" class="field-long" />



<button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" class="remove_field_button">Remove Field</button>
</div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
</body>

<script>

var max_fields      = 10;
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");
var remove_button   = $(".remove_field_button");

$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;
    if(total_fields < max_fields){
        $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="full_name" class="field-long" />');
        $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="email" class="field-long" />');
        $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mesaj" class="field-long" />');
    }
});
$(remove_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;
    if(total_fields>1){
        wrapper[0].childNodes[total_fields-1].remove();
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
    $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="full_name" class="field-long" />');
    $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="email" class="field-long" />');
    $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mesaj" class="field-long" />');
```

Every time you create a new field, it has the same `name=` value. When a multiple form fields are submitted with the the same names, it creates an array of values - just looking in request.POST will only find one of them.  You can retrieve these arrays via getlist and handle this in your view like this:

```
   if request.method=='POST':
        full_name = request.POST.getlist('full_name')
        email=request.POST.getlist('email')
        mesaj=request.POST.getlist('mesaj')
        for count, value in enumerate(full_name):
            #check to make sure all elements are present
            if full_name[count] and email[count] and mesaj[count]:
                contact=Contact.objects.create(                 
                    full_name=full_name[count],
                    email=email[count], 
                    mesaj=mesaj[count],
                 )
```

However, Django actually has a built in way of handling multiple forms of the same kind. Have a look at [FormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/) in the django docs

Comment: hi @SamSparx, i copy and paste your code but it didn't worked :(

Comment: Made a slight adjustment to code to make numbering system work more intuitively

Comment: Came up with a more robust way to handle unknown number of contacts

Comment: hi @SamSparx, i found another way, i am little bit busy, i will add here.